# Side navigation closes when I navigate to deeper levels in Doxygen output

Tags: doxygen

I am generating output in Doxygen with side navigation that has several levels. When I navigate using the left-side navigation pane, it shows what I have selected until I get to the 8th level down - then it collapses the menu and I have no clue where I'm at in the document.
Is there any way to stop the menu from collapsing?

[image: navigation image]

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Can you give a small example where you get / need 8 levels deep?

Comment: I am running 1.9.1.

Comment: Sorry - not sure what kind of examples you are looking for?

Comment: An example to  to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just check version 1.9.3 (the current version) as well as some changes in respect to the side bar took place (might solve the problem).

Comment: Running with 1.9.3 seems to resolve the issue - thank you so much!